# webapp on iOS download again when added to home screen

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, manifest

I've got a single page html5 application with a manifest file and many resources to be cached. When I open the page from the browser (both android chrome and ios safari) it starts downloading the file listed in the manifest. After that, I press "add to home screen" and the app-like icon is created but on iOS if I open the app from the icon in the home screen it downloads again every file listed in the manifest, this doesn not happen on android.

Is it supposed to behave like this or I am missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache" lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title>app</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=768, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable = no">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icona.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/icona.png">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">

    </head>

    <body>
    ...
```

manifest.appcache

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/cache-manifest');
?>
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
#lastupdate <2014 Jul 16 Wednesday 18:37:18>

/myresource1.png
/myresource2.png

NETWORK:
/myresource3.png
/myresource4.png


FALLBACK:
```

**UPDATE**

Before pressing add to home screen I wait the "cached" event, I know it has been fired because it close my progress bar

```
function cachedEvent(e) {               
    $('#progressBar').css('display','none');
}

applicationCache.addEventListener('cached', cachedEvent);
```

Comment: The top answer here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302501/html5-web-app-not-caching-when-added-to-home-screen-in-ios?rq=1

Comment: @MattS Thanks for the input, basically it says that when I add to home screen the files to be cached haven't been downloaded yet, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the home screen caches separately in the background, so if it's a lot of data it could take some time.

Comment: @MattS It could be, I just don't understand two things: I wait for the cached event to be fired, the downloading process should be over then; I checked server side and the whole list of files has been downloaded twice, from start to end.