# iOS: Web app added to home screen not working in offline mode

Tags: ios, caching, web-applications, offline, homescreen

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302501/html5-web-app-not-caching-when-added-to-home-screen-in-ios?rq=1) is similar, but the answer did not help.

The goal is to cache a single web page to the home screen, and launch this web page successfully even in offline mode.

Launching the web page from the home screen succeeds when there's a network, but it fails in offline mode because Safari complains there's no connection the server.

The web page contains this `meta` tag:

```
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"  />
```

Is this possible with web apps on iOS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We fixed this by supporting a cached version of the app with the `manifest` attribute as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="/cache.manifest">
....
</html>
```

The `cache.manifest` file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Version 0.0.2

NETWORK: *

CACHE:
ShareIconTutorial.png
HomeScreenIcon.png

FALLBACK:
```

Documentation is outdated on this topic because of PWAs, so hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a description of using offline cache on iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Answer (score 0):

apple-mobile-web-app-capable means,

> If content is set to yes, the web application runs in full-screen
>   mode; otherwise, it does not. The default behavior is to use Safari to
>   display web content. You can determine whether a webpage is displayed
>   in full-screen mode using the window.navigator.standalone read-only
>   Boolean JavaScript property.
>
> [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

If you want caching you can try a Progressive Web App and I do not think iOS supports it.